# My ubuntu keeps crashing and its really annoying

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, crash, read-only, systemd-journald

I installed ubuntu on an external samsung SSD t5 such that when i plug in the ssd my laptop boots from ubuntu and otherwise boots windows.

However when I am working on ubuntu it regularly will crash usually with different errors although the most common one is `systemd-journal Failed to write entry. Ignoring: read-only file system only`. I am really stuck as to why. I've been given advice like fix the ssd but I just am not technically competent enough to be able to do that with some more specific instructions. I don't even know what is wrong with it that needs fixing. Please could someone help me I really am at a loose end. Thank you so much in advance you are my hero if you can help me solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crash: systemd-journal Failed to write entry. Ignoring: read-only file system only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173738/crash-systemd-journal-failed-to-write-entry-ignoring-read-only-file-system-on)

Comment: I cannot work out how to update the firmware of the samsung t5 at all its so confusing sorry