# System sometimes failed to boot and crashes randomly (if succeeded) in Ubuntu 20.04, How to fix?

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.04, kernel, crash

So I have a laptop with model ASUS 553v using Ubuntu 20.04, no dual boot. There are problems when started booting and when it successfully booted then randomly crashes.

Problems when booting:

1. Randomly goes to BIOS ez mode from ASUS, but cannot go to GRUB and
   start the OS, just looping to BIOS again.
2. Randomly stuck in the ASUS logo and the fan starts to sound really noisy
3. (I don't know if it is a problem) It always shows [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1ejI.jpg) when booting. For detail, I typed the repeating messages

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS
(Firmware Bug): ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer.
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: Clearing orphaned inode
```

Problems when successfully booting:

1. System suddenly crashes and my screen becomes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkg60.jpg) after a random amount of time.
2. Doesn't crash but cannot open any apps including the terminal. (This usually leads to problem 1)
3. Doesn't crash but directed to Ubuntu Login UI and looped there. (This usually leads to problem 1)
4. It crashes when I open a game using SteamOS with Vulkan running, the error says something about read-swap error. (I forgot to take a pic of it, and now almost of the time my laptop fails to boot)

What I've tried:

1. I tried upgrading my kernel using UK Tools but it failed due to dpkg problem for the Linux header and I am confused so I stopped trying to upgrade it.
2. I tried to go to initramfs in the booting phase then run `fsck -f /dev/sda2` it took really long the first time so I restart the laptop for some reason and then I try it again and wait like about 10 hours but still it's not fixed.
3. I tried updating my firmware (though I don't know what firmware) through Ubuntu Software GUI, but it failed to update it.

I really don't understand much about OS and I know I might have made my laptop condition worse, but please can someone help me, I'm desperate :(. I also have the thought that all this happened because of my poor quality and old HDD because of this [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173738/crash-systemd-journal-failed-to-write-entry-ignoring-read-only-file-system-on) and I don't know how to upgrade my firmware or kernel manually.

Please tell me how to fix my laptop, or do I need to change my harddisk and all this problem gone? Thx in advance.

Comment: My Linux kernel version is 5.8 and the version I tried upgrading is 5.12.5

Comment: It looks like a hard-drive error, but it might be that the problem is really in the controller, or in the software communicating with the controller.  if this is a new problem, I'd suspect the hard drive.  do you have a spare to try?

Comment: @Jad Thank you for your comment, I tried using external HDD as the OS runner, and now it works just fine, so it turns out my hard-drive has an error or something.

Comment: I hate it when that happens.  if you need to recover an files from your drive, you might be well off using something like `ddrescue` (or `gddrescue` for a graphical interface) and/or using `foremost` or other recovery tools from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery